# Swiper slider custom transition effect

Tags: javascript, slider, css-transforms, swiper.js, html-framework-7

I've been trying to achieve create a custom effect for our beloved swiper slider, and i was hoping someone might have an idea to help me.
You can see the animated gif to see how it should be
[animation demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UAm1q.gif)

Ideally the transition would be 3D (with perspective)
[3d animation demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZJGir.gif)

I've been trying to achieve this using both the onProgress and setTranslate methods .
I am trying to find the proper rotate3D and transform origin values.

```
mySwiper.on('onProgress', function (s,progress) {
for (var a = 0; a < s.slides.length; a++) {
var slide = s.slides[a];
var slideProgress = slide.progress;

 if (slideProgress < 0) {
   var slideRotation = 90-(slideProgress *90);
   var slideOrigin= (100+(slideProgress*100));
 } else {
   var slideRotation = 90-(slideProgress *90);
   var slideOrigin= (100+(slideProgress*100))*-1;
 }
  slideOrigin=0; 

 $(slide).css({transform:'rotateY('+slideRotation+'deg)'}) 
}
});
```

any help appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

I'm interested in custom transition too.
But the one you're looking for already exists : 
https://github.com/nolimits4web/Swiper/blob/master/demos/17-effect-cube.html

```
var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
    pagination: '.swiper-pagination',
    effect: 'cube',
    grabCursor: true,
    cube: {
        shadow: true,
        slideShadows: true,
        shadowOffset: 20,
        shadowScale: 0.94
    }
});
```